# Show the output from loop in controller to the view in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, frameworks

Can't display data from **for** loop in yii2. 
Need to render **echo** from **controller** to **view** page.
But variable doesn't work in **view** properly

```
public function actionTest()
{   

 for($a = 0; $a <= 2; $a++)
      {
       for($b = 0; $b <= 2; $b++)
         {
            echo "$b $a </br>";
         }
      }

 return $this->renderContent('test', [ 

          ]);

}
```

output of **echo**

```
 0 0
 1 0
 2 0
 0 1
 1 1
 2 1
 0 2
 1 2
 2 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of variable were you trying to pass to the view?

I work with Laravel, not Yii, but you should be able to create an array with the paired values and then loop over that array variable inside the view.

You should also be able to remove the break element from the Controller and output that in the view.

```
public function actionTest() 
{   
    $data = [];
    for($a = 0; $a <= 2; $a++)
        {
            for($b = 0; $b <= 2; $b++)
            {
                $data[] = "$b $a";
            }
        }

    return $this->render('search', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's right answer. In view i just typed $data in foreach loop and it's display all.

Answer (score 0):

you should create an array and pass result of for loops to it
then pass result array to view;